# Unordered list with bullets AFTER first list item

Tags: css

[image: http://i.imgur.com/tToezlN.png]

I'm trying to achieve an effect like the one above but am unsure of the best way to do it. It it possible to use the unordered list and then change the styles so the bullets only appear on the inside?

If not would the best way be add a background image to each list item using pseudo to stop them showing before the first list item?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively simple, so I doubt you tried, but because it requires so little effort, here you have the solution: (ok, so maybe the solution is so glaringly obvious you missed it ;p )

http://jsfiddle.net/kVsce/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li:first-child { list-style: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going back to bed. I've been writing websites for nearly 2 years now and this was staring me in the face so hard I can't believe I missed it. Thanks man, I now feel like a complete dunce :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this..can modify it according to your need.

CSS

```
ul { background: #004A80; overflow:hidden;}
ul li { color: #3CBCFF; font-size: 18px; float: left; width: 65px; }
ul li span { color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; }  
ul li:first-child { list-style: none; }
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 2</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 3</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 4</span></li>                
</ul>
```